# Using Mechanize (Python) to click on a button

Tags: python, mechanize

I'm using Mechanize lib (with Python) to create a program to log in a system. But for that system the option Browser.Submit not works. So I'm trying to force my program to click in the button "login". Does anybody know if it's possible with Mechanize?

Answer (score 1):

You might consider looking at [twill](http://twill.idyll.org/python-api.html), if you haven't already. Twill is based on the mechanize package, and has a [submit function](http://twill.idyll.org/commands.html#forms) that can be used to click buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to have a look at [ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/) which provides a headless WebKit browser accessible via Python (basically a Python variant of [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)). Either should have no problem clicking on an arbitrary button (after filling out a form, or even evaluating some JS).

Answer (score 0):

Try RoboBrowser, which is built on top of Mechanize and Beautiful Soup.

Example code:

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
crawler = RoboBrowser(history=True)
crawler.open('http://www.whatever.com/')
search_form = crawler.get_form(attrs={'name':'formName') #This is the name found in <formname=formName>
search_form['keywords'] = 'search keywords' # In form[] specify the <input name=''> of the subfield within the form element that you're trying to fill in.
crawler.submit_form(search_form)`
```